# Как расшифровать зашифрованное с помощью xor сообщение?

Tags: visual-c++, c, c++

```
unsigned char encryptCBC(unsigned char *buffer, int size, unsigned char key, unsigned char CBC)
{
    // <ToDo>: implement encryption algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        buffer[i] = buffer[i] ^ key;
        buffer[i] = buffer[i] ^ CBC;
        CBC = buffer[i];

    }
    return CBC;
}
```

Как расшифровать то, что зашифровала эта функция?

Comment: Вызвать ее еще раз с теми же ключами.

Comment: Не прокатит, ибо "CBC = buffer[i]"...

Comment: @klopp, вы правы. Можно так

    u_char decrypt (u_char *buf, int sz, u_char key, u_char CBC) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
          buf[i] = buf[i] ^ key;
          buf[i] = buf[i] ^ CBC;
          CBC = buf[i] ^ key ^ CBC;
        }
        return CBC;
    }

а вызывать их так

    encryptCBC(buf,b_size,'a','0');

и

    decryptCBC(buf,b_size,'a','0');

тогда расшифрует (это первый блок (я проверил)). Понятно, что в шифровку-дешифровку следующих блоков надо передавать следующий байт ключа (в цикле) и возвращаемое на предыдущей итерации CBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите на картинку, изображающую [схему работы CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29).

Вектор инициализации (IV, у Вас — CBC) для следующего шага берется из шифртекста предыдущего. Соответственно, все что нужно — запомнить `buffer[i]` до расшифровки:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    unsigned char next_iv = buffer[i];
    buffer[i] = buffer[i] ^ key ^ iv;
    iv = next_iv;
}
```

Про проход цикла в обратную сторону — чушь.

Answer (score 2):

Вдумчивое созерцание приведённого кода вызывает ощущение, что функция применяет сразу два разных XOR-алгоритма. Первым делом она шифрует методом XOR, применяя ко всем байтам одинаковый для всего блока однобайтовый ключик. Фактически, это означает, что ключом для блока является строка одинаковых символов такой же длины, как и сам блок. На мой взгляд, это довольно стрёмная практика (можно было бы использовать ключ хотя бы из 2-х байт :) ). Затем функция, видимо, пытается применить другой XOR-алгоритм (Cipher Block Chaining) для связывания блоков. Об этом говорит то, что она принимает на входе переменную, название которой подозрительно похоже на аббревиатуру алгоритма, а в конце возвращает её же, но уже проXORенную с зашифрованными байтами. Нечто очень похожее как раз и нужно делать для связывания блоков этим методом.

Странность лишь в том, что в классическом варианте алгоритма связывающим блоки звеном должен быть не один единственный байт, а целый блок, зашифрованный на предыдущем шаге (или его имитация - для первого шага). Видимо, тут применяется особая модификация алгоритма для тех, кто любит не только однобайтовые ключи, но и однобайтовую сцепку блоков. Переменная CBC выражает собой весь предыдущий блок в одном байте. Она как бы накапливает в одном байте нечто, зависящее от ранее зашифрованных байт. На этапе шифровки всё происходит естественным образом. Для накопления нужен предыдущий зашифрованный байт, который как раз и был только что получен. Но и на этапе расшифровки для накопления всё равно требуется предыдущий зашифрованный байт, однако в буфере его уже не будет - его место займёт расшифрованный.

Короче говоря, я не думаю, что вызов этой же функции на зашифрованный буфер приведёт к его расшифровке. Скорее всего он просто всё сломает. Возможно, если поменять строчки местами (сначала XORить с CBC, а потом - с ключом), то это восстановит возможность шифровать и расшифровывать одной функцией, которая так привлекает в XOR-алгоритмах. Но уверенности нет. Может и не сработать. Нужно проверять.

Comment: В прошлом вопросе выяснилось, что у автора это такой оригинальный размер блока — 8 бит (платформозависимо). Такой вот блочный шифр на грани фола.

Comment: такое задание было по информационной безопасности на учебе)зашифровать и расшифровать файл)спасибо)все работает

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно читаем [википедию](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation). Там на пальцах изложена схема шифрования и дешифровки.

**P.S.** CBC это не способ шифрования, а способ "укладки" шифрованных блоков

**P.P.S.** Все начинается с вектора инициализации!

Answer (score -1):

аналогично, только цикл должен идти с конца (т.к. у вас каждый следующий блок связывается с предыдущим зашифрованым блоком) + операции в обратном порядке

```
// логика для блоков следующая (впрочем для символов тоже)
encrypted[i] = crypted[i] ^ crypted[i-1] (CBC) ^ key
```

не стоит забывать что у вас для первого блока CBC не будет (или будет установленный в какое-то начальное значение)

Comment: там в CBC ноль передается первоначально!то есть оставить все тоже самое только с конца по циклу идти?
for(int i=size;i>=0;i--){
  buffer[i]=buffer[i]^key;
  buffer[i]=buffer[i]^CBC;
  CBC=buffer[i];
  
 }
 return CBC;

Comment: да походу порядок итерации не имеет значения, кроме того вам надо поменять функцию и для параметра `key` сделать такой же тип как и для открытого сообщения, - `buffer[i] = buffer[i] ^ key[i];`